# GroupBy and Sum

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I read a lot of GroupBy + Sum topics but I didn't understand how to use it.

I have a list of contacts, and in this list, i want to get the state (which appears more).

So my code is:

```
contacts.GroupBy(i => i.Address.State.ToUpperInvariant());
```

In this GroupBy, I want to know the state that appears more (and remove the case of "" because empty state is not important to me).

How do I do it?

I was thinking in something like this:

```
contacts.GroupBy(i => i.Address.State.ToUpperInvariant()).Select(i => i.Max());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like:

```
var counts = contacts
    .Where(c => c.State != string.Empty)
    .GroupBy(i => i.Address.State, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Select(grp => new { State = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count());
```

`GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Since [IGrouping<TKey, TSource>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<TSource>`, you can use the `Count` extension method to get the number of elements in the group.